# What does it mean if Android MediaCodec dequeueOutputBuffer returns -1?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I followed the official Android documentation to setup an encoder for my audio input using a MediaCodec object. But the method dequeueOutputBuffer in the code below always returns -1. What does this return value mean?

My code:

```
/*configuarion of MediaCodec object*/
codec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("audio/mp4a-latm");
MediaFormat format = new MediaFormat();
format.setString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME, "audio/mp4a-latm");
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, 44100);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 64 * 1024);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_AAC_PROFILE,MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.AACObjectHE);
codec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

codec.start();
 ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = codec.getInputBuffers();
 ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = codec.getOutputBuffers();

/*main loop to encode audio data*/
 for (;;) {
   int inputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1); -->this is never zero so data should be written correctly!
   if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {

     // write data from audiorecord in queue
     inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
     inputBuffer.clear();

     inputBuffer.put(buf);-->data from audiorecord object

     encoder.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, buf.length, 0, 0);
     codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, ...);

   }

   int outputBufferIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0);-------->>> "-1"
   if (outputBufferIndex >= 0) {

       //do something but never called because outputbufferindex is always -1??
```

Comment: The data won't be ready right away.  You may need to submit several buffers before output is available.  See also http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ .

Comment: what are the buf.length size? do you send somehow normal frames to encoder? also try to change codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 0) to codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 10000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting -1 as return value when you have passed non negative `timeoutUS` indicates that call to `dequeueOutputBuffer` has timed out. According to Android Sample, it returns following integer

```
 public static final int INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER = -1;
```

Comment: It means encoder is currently busy in current iteration of loop. You need to wait till encoder completes its job.

Answer (score -1):

As far as my knowledge goes, you have to increment the `timestamp` field in `"encoder.queueInputBuffer"` everytime because if the same timestamp is given everytime, buffer may be dropped by `encoder`.